# ListActivity Does Not Show Any Entries In The ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem

This seems to be a problem that is encountered often, but couldn't find a solution for my situation among those that are offered.

So I have an Activity that extends a ListActivity and the following code within it:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(playersDatabaseName, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        SQLStatement = "create table if not exists Players_And_Scores(_id integer primary key autoincrement, Player String, Score String);";
        db.execSQL(SQLStatement);


        cv.put("Player", WelcomeActivity.playersName);
        cv.put("Score", GameActivity.currentScore);
        try
        {
            db.insertOrThrow("Players_And_Scores", null, cv);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("SQLiteException", cv.toString() + " is there already");
        }

        c = db.query("Players_And_Scores", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                              c, new String[] {"Player", "Score"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);

        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This does set up a listview and every time the entry is added a new row is added into a database a new line is added to a listwiev. However all of the lines are empty. So it recognizes the number of lines, but not the contents.

I was thinking if I should add something to xml so I've been playing with it without result. 
Here is what I have currently for xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- the android:id is important -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
here is the logcat:

```
  04-23 03:05:16.083    3332-3332/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    04-23 03:05:16.193    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/can read﹕ true
    04-23 03:05:16.193    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/this﹕ State                   Capital
    04-23 03:05:16.193    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/this﹕ ----------------        ---------------
    04-23 03:05:16.193    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/this﹕ Alabama                 Montgomery
   State=Wyoming
    04-23 03:05:16.473    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/SQLiteException﹕ Capital=Cheyenne State=Wyoming is there already
    04-23 03:05:16.483    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/db﹕ []
    04-23 03:05:16.513    3332-3332/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 485K, 16% free 3261K/3856K, paused 5ms, total 13ms
    04-23 03:05:16.533    3332-3332/statesgame.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb88f79f0, tid 3332
    04-23 03:05:16.573    3332-3332/statesgame.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    04-23 03:05:16.573    3332-3332/statesgame.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
    04-23 03:05:17.453    3332-3332/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 15% free 3298K/3856K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
    04-23 03:05:17.453    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/enteract﹕ act
    04-23 03:05:17.533    3332-3332/statesgame.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    04-23 03:05:18.813    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:18.813    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cursorEntirs﹕ 3
    04-23 03:05:18.813    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cCount﹕ 50
    04-23 03:05:19.143    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:19.143    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cursorEntirs﹕ 33
    04-23 03:05:19.143    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cCount﹕ 50
    04-23 03:05:19.313    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:19.313    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cursorEntirs﹕ 34
    04-23 03:05:19.313    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cCount﹕ 50
    04-23 03:05:19.483    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:19.483    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cursorEntirs﹕ 5
    04-23 03:05:19.483    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cCount﹕ 50
    04-23 03:05:19.623    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:19.623    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cursorEntirs﹕ 2
    04-23 03:05:19.623    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/cCount﹕ 50
    04-23 03:05:19.743    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:19.893    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:20.063    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:20.213    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:20.533    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:20.763    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/buttn﹕ Click
    04-23 03:05:20.793    3332-3332/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 30K, 13% free 3427K/3896K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
    04-23 03:05:20.793    3332-3332/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 12% free 3520K/3996K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
    04-23 03:05:20.803    3332-3332/statesgame.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.618MB for 1127532-byte allocation
    04-23 03:05:20.823    3332-3341/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 4621K/5100K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
    04-23 03:05:20.873    3332-3332/statesgame.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    04-23 03:09:38.607    3439-3439/statesgame.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    04-23 03:09:38.607    3439-3439/statesgame.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ce5b20)
    04-23 03:09:38.607    3439-3439/statesgame.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: statesgame.app, PID: 3439
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for statesgame.app; is package not installed?
                at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for statesgame.app; is package not installed?
                at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:376)
                at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:329)
                at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-23 03:09:39.737    3468-3468/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    04-23 03:09:39.787    3468-3468/statesgame.app I/can read﹕ true
    04-23 03:09:39.797    3468-3468/statesgame.app I/this﹕ State                   Capital
    04-23 03:09:39.797    3468-3468/statesgame.app I/this﹕ ----------------        ---------------
    04-23 03:09:39.797    3468-3468/statesgame.app I/this﹕ Alabama                 Montgomery
    04-23 03:09:39.817    3468-3468/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 109K, 7% free 3230K/3448K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
    04-23 03:09:39.827    3468-3468/statesgame.app I/SQLiteException﹕ Capital=Montgomery State=Alabama is there already

    04-23 03:10:05.507    3468-3468/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 12% free 3428K/3892K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
    04-23 03:10:05.507    3468-3468/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 12% free 3518K/3992K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
    04-23 03:10:05.507    3468-3468/statesgame.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.616MB for 1127532-byte allocation
    04-23 03:10:05.527    3468-3477/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 4619K/5096K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
    04-23 03:10:05.577    3468-3468/statesgame.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    04-23 03:18:27.315    3575-3575/statesgame.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    04-23 03:18:29.785    3575-3575/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 276K, 11% free 3456K/3844K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
    04-23 03:18:29.785    3575-3575/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 11% free 3518K/3944K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
    04-23 03:18:29.785    3575-3575/statesgame.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.616MB for 1127532-byte allocation
    04-23 03:18:29.805    3575-3584/statesgame.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 4619K/5048K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
    04-23 03:18:29.875    3575-3575/statesgame.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

**Edit**
Added manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="statesgame.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="statesgame.app.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="statesgame.app.GameActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="statesgame.app.ScoresActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scores" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: My activity shown as such]

I start my activity this way:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoresActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Have you extended in your activity `ListActivity` ?

Comment: Have your tried debugging your code? Do you get the data from database ?

Comment: @GrIsHu hmm.. didn't try that. Thought that was a layout problem. Will try to do it right now.

Comment: I think you are not able to get the data from the database.

Comment: @GrIsHu what would be the best way to see if I have it in there? Is there a nice method to retrieve a the data from cursor or adapter? Or should I just go ahead and turn on debugging and the data will show up?

Comment: Check out my answer and try.

Comment: just change the sql statement and see ;SQLStatement = "create table if not exists Players_And_Scores(_id integer primary key autoincrement, Player Text, Score Text);";

Comment: @Gautami it didn't help.

Comment: That doesn't explain why are your items blank, but you've created a layout.xml and never use it. You use deprecated constants. You're querying database in UI thread.

Comment: @DoctororDrive About layout: ListActivity and adapter are supposed to set it. 2) What deprecated constants do you mean? 3)For my purposes I can run it on UI thread my db is not gonna be bigger than 20 entries.

Comment: @user3081519 you should use setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name) before setListAdapter() to use your layout, otherwise the default one is used. 2) fill_parent is now match_parent if your'e targeting min API level 8 or more. 3) It's still better to use CursorLoader.

Comment: @DoctororDrive I am telling you one last time: 1) You do not setContentView explicitly in ListActivity. Google it. 2) Doesn't matter at all. And never did. 3)Also irrelevant. You are not contributing at all to the topic of the discussion and if you don't want to do so - just move along.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
      Cursor cursor = db.query("Players_And_Scores", new String[] 
     {"Player","Score"}, null, null, null);
       startManagingCursor(cursor);

        // THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
        String[] columns = new String[] { "Player", "Score"};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
         cursor , columns, new int[] {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2}, 0);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: For some reason changing the code to a given sample gave me this: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: Post your full logcat in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, took a little while to get rid of redundant logs i put in there.

Comment: This log is without your suggested implementation above, just the stable version I have currently.

Comment: What is the name of your activity ?

Comment: How this activity is shown ? From where you are calling this activity?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Wierdly enough, I simply changed my cursor object to this:

```
c = db.query("Players_And_Scores", new String[]{"_id", "Player", "Score"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Adding all the rows of my database explicitly solved the problem, but unfortunately only one entry `"Players"` gets displayed. In order to place more entries in a ListView row I will probably need to create a custom adapter.